# Wordpress Paths

Tags: php, wordpress

We are currently moving from an in house CMS solution to wordpress, while this will present some challenges right now, I'm having a couple of issues right now that I'm having a hard time sorting and that are delaying the move to the next tasks.

**Page Paths**

I've downloaded a plugin ( **Post Tags and Categories for Pages** ) which allows me to set Categories to pages like you can by default to posts, but my real problem is that it's not assuming the Categories permalinks, so if I have a category called *category1* and a page *page1* I want the link to be http://example.com/category1/page1/ but it's only showing as http://example.com/page1/, is there any plugin or code change that allow me to do just this?

**Page Extensions**

My second issue is with page extensions, we have many pages that are required to have an extension, like a *thanks.html* page, but as far as I can tell, no way of doing this wordpress, I could try doing this through the htaccess file, but there's some situations ( Old CMS ) where we have different pages but with the same name and different extension, like thanks.php and thanks.html.

Thanks for any help

Comment: What do you mean by extension pages... do you mean you need to access an extra page E.G. you have `/category/page/` and then you want to be able to access a chid page of that page like /category/page/extension` ?

Comment: For your "page extensions" issue: Get the "Simple 301 Redirects" plugin and build out your redirects - you can do it for a variety of extensions, redirecting to the new, common page.

Answer (score 0):

So for your first answer, you can format your URLS really easily in Wordpress.

From the WP admin main menu go to `settings > Permalinks`

Then use this `/%category%/%postname%` It should be pretty self-explanatory what the string does.

You can find out more about Permalinks [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) in the docs

For your second question... If I understand it correctly, you can simply create a new *sub page*. To do this, simply create a new page and set the parent from within the create a new page screen. See more info on that [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#To_create_a_subpage) in the docs

Comment: Yeah I've already did the necessary changes to the custom permalinks in Wordpress but the issue still remains, if I add Categories to Posts it will show the categories in the path, while if I add them to the Pages it won't appear in the URL, so something like this for the category1:

Posts
http://example.com/category1/post1/ - This works

Pages
http://example.com/page1/ - This doesn't' work for a page that has category1 set as category, it simply ignores the category path for the URL

Answer (score 0):

First problem can solve easily by changing the permalink structure in the permalink settings page.

You can solve your second problem by allowing WordPress to add . in the page title. This link will help you to do that https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/231952